# Traversing a binary tree using a list

Tags: python, list, binary-tree

**code.py**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data

def inOrder(root):
    if root:
        inOrder(root.left)
        print (root.data)
        inOrder(root.right)

def preOrder(root):
    if root:
        print (root.data)
        preOrder(root.left)
        preOrder(root.right)

def postOrder(root):
    if root:
        postOrder(root.left)
        postOrder(root.right)
        print (root.data)
```

I implemented a binary tree traversal by creating Node using a class.
I now want to implement binary tree traversal using only a list without using class.

Tree = [1, [2, [4,[],[]], [5,[],[]] ], [3, [], []] ]

I want to know how to implement it using this list.
It is too difficult for me.

Comment: Try writing helper functions to access the data, left child, and right child of a node in the list representation. The helper functions might help you see what your code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

The binary tree as list seems fairly straightforward.

The data is `node/sub_arr[0]`, The left node is another sub array `sub_arr[1]` and the right node is `sub_arr[2]`.

In the code. I merely replace `node.left` with `tree[1]`, `node.right` with `tree[2]` and `data` with `tree[0]`.

```
Tree = [1, [2, [4, [], []], [5, [], []]], [3, [], []]]


def inOrder(tree):
    if tree:
        inOrder(tree[1])  # Left
        print(tree[0])
        inOrder(tree[2])  # Right


def preOrder(tree):
    if tree:
        print(tree[0])
        preOrder(tree[1])  # Left
        preOrder(tree[2])  # Right


def postOrder(tree):
    if tree:
        postOrder(tree[1])  # Left
        postOrder(tree[2])  # Right
        print(tree[0])


print('In order')
inOrder(tree=Tree)
print('Pre Order')
preOrder(tree=Tree)
print('Post Order')
postOrder(tree=Tree)

#Output
In order
4
2
5
1
3
Pre Order
1
2
4
5
3
Post Order
4
5
2
3
1
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand how to access a tree of lists.
With your help I understood it properly.

Comment: Welcome. Glad to know it helped. Do consider marking the answer correct to help someone else as well in future.